# Usar dos cuentas de GitHub en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows, github, cuenta-usuario

Tengo un problema con los repositorios de GitHub en Visual Studio (no Visual Studio Code). Resulta que tengo varios repositorios en mi PC con dos cuentas diferentes, y quiero que cuando suba cambios al repositorio de la cuenta A se hagan con el usuario A, y cuando suba cambios al repositorio de la cuenta B se hagan con el usuario B. He estado jugando con esto, pero siempre me sube el código con el mismo usuario (tanto en el repositorio de la cuenta A como en el de la cuenta B). Cómo puedo hacer para que Visual Studio me suba los cambios con la cuenta A o B según el repositorio dónde esté? Este es un ejemplo:

[image: Commits hechos en el repositorio de GitHub]

Cómo podéis ver, he subido los cambios correctamente, pero el primero desde "farrufi" (la cuenta des de la que quiero que me los suba en este repositorio concreto), pero los últimos me los ha subido desde "6q4598", la otra cuenta de GitHub que tengo. Esto no debería verse así, si no que todos los cambios se deberían subir desde "farrufi" solamente.

Se puede automatizar/configurar esto en Visual Studio? O tengo cada vez que quiera cambiar de repositorio/cuenta/usuario volver a reiniciar las credenciales de GitHub?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y perdón por el tostón, no supe cómo resumir el problema.

)

**Edito nuevamente el post:**

Al final lo solucioné añadiendo mi otro usuario de GitHub cómo colaborador de mi repositorio. És una solución que no me encanta pero és la única que me ha servido.

Comment: Tampoco entiendo porque me deja subir los cambios desde otra cuenta si tengo el repositorio privado... En teoría, si lo tengo privado no me debería dejar no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los datos del usuario que realiza el commit corresponde al correo electrónico que esta configurado en git. Existe una configuración global y una local para cada repositorio. Puedes configurar el correo electrónico distinto en cada repositorio local.

Para conocer el correo configurado en el directorio de tu repositorio local

```bash
git config user.email
```

Para cambiar el correo

```bash
git config user.email "tucorreo@tudominio.com"
```

También puedes cambiar la configuración global usando `--global`

```bash
git config --global user.email "tucorreo@tudominio.com"
```

[referencia en github](https://docs.github.com/es/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo :) 
Ya intenté esto, pero parece no funcionar. También me gustaría encontrar una forma de hacerlo desde el propio Visual Studio para no tener que picar los comandos. De todos modos, lo volveré a probar ya que quizás me equivoqué en algo.